# HTML5 video breaks iPad app orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation, html5-video

I have an iPad app that contains a UIWebView that gets filled by a client of mine. The app is designed to run in portrait mode only and I've set the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation accordingly in every viewcontroller in the app. I've also set it in the Plist.

When a user plays an HTML5 video in the webview and chooses the fullscreen button and rotates the iPad to landscape, the video plays in landscape. However, if they press the "done" button while its still in landscape, the video closes and the app underneath, including the status bar, is in landscape.

If the user then rotates to portrait everything is fixed and locked in portrait.

How can I avoid it being in landscape mode after the video is closed? It looks terrible.